# How to exclude certain modules from a support library?

Tags: android, build.gradle

Please let me know how to specify the exclude to remove modules like "fingerprint". I have tried using exclude group: 'android.hardware', module: 'fingerprint' but did not work.
Appreciate your help.

```
<root>: 45486
    <default>: 1
    android: 23585
        accessibilityservice: 7
        accounts: 6
        animation: 64
        app: 365
        bluetooth: 6
        content: 356
            pm: 31
            res: 101
        database: 66
            sqlite: 10
        graphics: 352
            drawable: 123
                shapes: 3
            pdf: 3
        hardware: 20
            display: 3
            fingerprint: 11
        location: 12
        media: 287
            audiofx: 8
            browse: 19
            session: 92
        net: 68
            http: 1
            wifi: 12
        opengl: 40
```

Comment: The support library is rather large, perhaps a better practice would be to INCLUDE only the libraries that you need, e.g.{ compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'}

Answer (score 2):

In gradle file

```
dependencies {
compile('gradle dependency name') {
    exclude module: 'module name'
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for replying. That is what I have been doing but not working for certain modules. Can you let me know how to mention the group name and the module name for "fingerprint" ?

Comment: For example dependencies {
    compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
 }

Comment: :) That one was easy, but trying to exclude "fingerprint" does not seem to be.